Joseph Scaliger and Bible Chronology
What year did Scaliger date the Exodus? Is there a list of his Chronology in English anywhere. I'm trying to find cross comparisons of ancient writers and their dating systems.

Joseph Scaliger was not exactly "ancient", by the definition used her.  Give more detail of what you want, please.

The Seder Olam Rabbah is an attempt by a Jewish Rabbi to produce a chronology of the Jewish people and hence Bible history.  It was written in either the 1st or 2nd century AD/CE.  It is available in full, free, online.
Archbishop Usher would be perhaps the best known early English language writer to attempt a chronology.
Going forward into the early 20th century there is the Belgian Jesuit Priest, Valerius Coucke, setting the date of the Exodus from Egypt at 1446 BCE, see wikipedia. Independently, not knowing of Valerius Coucke's work, Seventh Day Adventist Edwin Thiele set the Exodus at 1445 BCE in the 1940s and 50s see "Mysterious Numbers of the Hebrew Kings".  Rodger C Young found the one year error in Thiele's work, so the date now agrees at 1446 BCE.
Archaeological discovery of Assyrian King Lists, etc, and Tyrian King Lists, and Egyptian archaeological discoveries have all transformed our ability to date Old Testament events.  These discoveries began in the late 1700s and continue to the present day.
Seeing as you call Scaliger "ancient" it is not easy to know what chronologists from what centuries you would want to include.
Finally, Matthew Henry, living in the Puritan era, wrote a Bible Commentary for the whole of the Old Testament and the first books of the New Testament. He is still in print and, I expect, free online. He would have read widely the writings of others.  He sometimes writes about dates of biblical events, such as what he writes about chapter 1 of the Book of Daniel. His comments give us a good idea of the extent of the accuracies and (rather more) inaccuracies of the knowledge of biblical chronology in the Puritan era.
Postscript
(Mostly from wikipedia)
In chronological order of the published works on chronology.
Attributed to Rabbi "Jose Ben Halafta" -
Published "Seder Olam Rabbah" about AD 160, a chronology from the Creation to Alexander the Great, with a brief supplement
up to the time of Hadrian.  The Persian period is understood as being not 210 years, but only 52 years. (Some Christians, e.g Pastor Steve Rudd, Canada, claim this may have been a deliberate ploy to give the impression that the 490 years of Daniel 9v24 had not yet arrived by the time of Christ, i.e. the death of Jesus of Nazareth could not be the end-point of the 70 weeks of Daniel 9v24.)
In it, the Jubilee Year in Ezekiel 40v1, the 14th year after the Fall of Jerusalem, is called the "17th" Jubilee: this was later found by Rodger C. Young (www.rcyoung.org) to agree to the exact year with the Exodus date calculated by Valerius Coucke and published in the 1920s.  The implication is that the author had access to extra-biblical data stored by the priesthood in Jerusalem.
The Talmud -
Its authors cannot agree if the Jubilee Cycle was 49 years or 50 years.
Eusebius (about 262-339) -
Published, before 300, the work "Chronicle", a calendar of events from the Creation to Eusebius's time.
Dionysius Exiguus
year 525 - Devised the Christian Calendar of BC and AD, our Lord Jesus Christ being (calculated to have been) born in AD 1.
Reverend Hugh Broughton (1549-1612) -
Sometime between 1587 and 1591 he published "A Concent of Scripture". He travelled extensively, both in Great Britain and Europe, to promote his chronology.  His chronology is summarily mentioned in chapter 1 of Matthew Henry's Commentary on Daniel.  This summary of Matthew Henry is thus:
Mr Broughton observes the proportion of times in God's government since the coming out of Egypt:
thence to their entering Canaan - 40 years;
thence to the dividing of the land - 7 years;
thence to the 1st year of Samuel 7 Jubilees - 343 years;
thence to the 1st year of Captivity 10 Jubilees - 490 years;
thence to the Return from Captivity - 70 years;
thence to the death of Christ 70 "weeks" - 490 years;
thence to the destruction of Jerusalem - 40 years.
If Hugh Broughton accepted the birth of our Lord as 1 AD, and that he was crucified at 33 years of age then his death would have been AD 34; the decree of Cyrus 457 BC (no year zero); the beginning of Captivity 527; the 1st year of Samuel 1017; the 7th year after Entry into the Promised Land 1360; the Fall of Walls of Jericho 1366; the Exodus 1406 BC.
Joseph Scaliger (1540-1609) -
Published in 1606 "Thesaurus Temporum", a reconstruction of the lost "Chronicle" of Eusebius, including every chronological relic extant in Greek and Latin.
Dionysius Petavius (aka "Denis Petau") (1583-1652)
1627 "Opus De Doctrina Temporum";
1628, 1629, 1633, 1657 "Tabulae Chronologicae"
("A summary of it appeared in 1633 (1635, 1641, etc.) under the title of "Rationarium Temporum", of which numerous reprints and translations into French, English, and Italian have been made." -  wikipedia)
English translation (with additions by others) published 1651 "The History of the World: OR, an Account of Time" by Dionysius Petavius
https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=_uG9TqoXu1IC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false
The end of chapter 5 of Denis Petau's book gives the 6th year after entering the Promised Land of Canaan/Israel as 1486 BC.  This would put the Fall of the Walls of Jericho at 1492; and thus the Exodus at 1532 BC.  I cannot find the date of the Exodus from any writings of Scaliger. Seeing as Denis Petau built his studies heavily upon the work of Scaliger it might be possible to assume the date of the Exodus for Scaliger was similar to that of Petau.  There is an article about the work of both these men on JSTOR by Anthony Grafton, "Joseph Scaliger and Historical Chronology: the Rise and Fall of a Discipline".
John Lightfoot (1602-1675) -
Published from 1644 to 1650 the installments of his "Harmony of the Four Evangelists..." in which he dated Creation to 3929 BC.
Archbishop Ussher (1581-1656) -
Published (1st edition) 1650 & (2nd edition) 1654 "Annals of the Old Testament, deduced from the first origins of the world", in which he dated the beginning of Creation to 4004 BC, October, 22nd, at 6pm.
In modern times Archbishop Ussher's Chronology, especially, has received considerable criticism: in 1990 Terry Pratchet and Neil Gaiman alleged the Archbishop Ussher was wrong by almost a quarter of an hour. Other notable criticisms have been offered by Princeton Professor William Henry Green in "Primeval Chronology" (1890) and by B.B. Warfield "On the Antiquity and Unity of the Human Race" (1911).  The real issue is whether the genealogies in Genesis chapters 5 and 11 are father to son genealogies, or whether they contain gaps. The view they contain gaps is well argued by Dr John Millam in "The Genesis Genealogies" (2010): https://reasons.org/explore/publications/articles/the-genesis-genealogies
